# Flutter Textfield cursor focus moves to another textfield when new widget appears with provider watch

Tags: flutter, focus, cursor, textfield, provider

[Video](https://petner.notion.site/petner/video-f730866c2fba4ee58ba2722b35c0b20b)

As shown in video, with provider watch, textfield cursor focus moves to the upper textfield when new Text widgets appear above the textfields.

This doesn't happen when Text widget appears below the textfield widgets.

Replacing `if (testPvd.showA)` with Visibility widget does prevent the cursor from moving, however I still don't understand this happening.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  var controller1 = TextEditingController();
  var controller2 = TextEditingController();
  var controller3 = TextEditingController();
  var controller4 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TestProvider testPvd = context.watch<TestProvider>();

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 20),
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                child: Text('showA'),
                onTap: () {
                  testPvd.updateToggleButton('A');
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20),
              InkWell(
                child: Text('showB'),
                onTap: () {
                  testPvd.updateToggleButton('B');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          if (testPvd.showA) Text('A'),
          if (testPvd.showB) Text('B'),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          TextField(controller: controller1),
          TextField(controller: controller2),
          TextField(controller: controller3),
          TextField(controller: controller4),
          // if (testPvd.showA) Text('A'),
          // if (testPvd.showB) Text('B'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool showA = false;
  bool showB = false;

  updateToggleButton(String value) {
    if (value == 'A') showA = !showA;
    if (value == 'B') showB = !showB;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Expected the cursor to stay on current textfield.